# Bash script to move files yy/mm/dd

Tags: linux, bash, centos, sh

Wondering if anyone can help with a bash script for the following.

Have a folder `blah/` which includes `*.txt` files which gets updated daily.

I need to move the txt files daily to a `/archive/yy/mm/dd` folder format.

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far? If so, please share them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following script:

```
d=/archive/$(date +%Y/%m/%d)
mkdir -p "$d"
find ./blah -type f -name *.txt -exec mv {} "$d" \;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the above, it nearly works, the 2017 gets created but the month is getting created as "24" /archive/2017/24/10

Comment: If you want to automate this process, read on cronjobs.
This will allow you to execute the above command daily, at any time you want.
For example i use cronjobs to bakup my files daily on 12 am.

Comment: @Steve I just had to change the `%M` to `%m`! small typo :)

Comment: `mkdir -p` might be a small improvement - it could run twice in one day without error and it could traverse the directory structure in any order.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for pointing that out, updated the answer

Comment: You only need one call to `date` in each of the `-exec`s: `$(date +%Y/%m/%d)`.

Comment: There's also no need to call `mkdir` for each file, because the directory to create is independent of the file. Just call `mkdir /archive/$(date +%Y/%m/%d` once before calling find.